# Mongo aggregation no funciona el $or

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Buenos días tengo una api en node.js con un aggregate de mongo para sacar unos registros de bases de datos.

La question es que tengo que sacar registros que coincidan con la zona "A" o "B" y canal "1" o "2"

Por alguna razón el aggregate no esta funcionando. Devuelve registros pero no de forma correcta. No consigo arreglarlo.

Os dejo el aggregate Gracias

```
{
  '$match': {
    year: 2020,
    '$or': [ {zona: "A"}, {zona: "B"}, {canal: "1"}, {canal: "2"} ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que el operador [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) tal como la tienes actualmente se evalúa sobre las 4 condiciones que estás pasando como argumento, y eso no es lo que has planteado en tu pregunta:

> ... tengo que sacar registros que coincidan con la *zona "A" o "B"* **y** *canal "1" o "2"*

Observa que he puesto en negrilla **y**.

Actualmente en tu etapa de agregación tienes la siguiente sentencia:

> registros que coincidan con la zona "A" o "B" **o** canal "1" o "2".

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, debes usar un operador [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) que envuelva a tus dos condiciones `$or`.

Debes pensar un poco en la forma en que se traduce tu proposición:

> ... tengo que sacar registros que coincidan con la zona "A" o "B" y canal "1" o "2"

en un predicado de [álgebra booleana](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81lgebra_de_Boole).

Supongamos que `{ zona: "A" }` es `a`, `{ zona: "B" }` es `b`, `{ canal: "1" }` es `c` y `{ canal: "2" }` es `d`. Entonces tu proposición se convierte en:

> `(a ᐯ b) ᐱ (c ᐯ d)`

Es decir:

> `(a OR b) AND (c OR d)`.

Para plasmar esto en una etapa de agregación debemos entender cómo funciona el operador `$and`. De la documentación se tiene:

```js
{
  $and: ["expresion1", "expresion2", ...]
}
```

Cada expresión dentro de la lista de expresiones debe evaluar a un valor `true` o `false`.

Si todas las expresiones evalúan a `true` entonces el operador `$and` devuelve `true`, en caso contrario devuelve `false`.

Viendo esto, y sabiendo que en el predicado tenemos una evaluación `AND` sobre el resultado de evaluaciones `OR`, es sencillo escribir la expresión de agregación de la siguiente forma:

```js
{
  $and: [
    { $or: [{zona: "A"}, {zona: "B"}] },
    { $or: [{canal: "1"}, {canal: "2"}] }
  ]
}
```

De esta forma si estarás expresando tu proposición correctamente en la etapa de agregación:

```js
{
  "$match": {
    "year": 2020,
    "$and": [
      {
        "$or": [
          {
            "zona": "A"
          },
          {
            "zona": "B"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "$or": [
          {
            "canal": "1"
          },
          {
            "canal": "2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Puedes ver el siguiente [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_ypb3XSvHOz) donde sólo 3 documentos de los 7 que existen superan el filtro tal como lo especificas en tu proposición.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu detallada respuesta. Te lo agradezco muchisimo